# How does this example work in Bjarne Stroustrup's C++ Programming Language works?

Tags: c++, reference, constants, pass-by-reference

I'm reading *[The C++ Programming Language, 4th Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321563840)* (by [Bjarne Stroustrup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bjarne_Stroustrup)) about [references](/questions/tagged/references).

He has the following code example:

```
void f (const vector<double>& v){
    double d1 = v[1];
    v[2] = 7;

    v.push_back(d1);
}
```

My question is: since `v` is passed as const how can we change `v` in second and third statements in the function?

I tried compiling the code and it does not work:

> error: assignment of read-only location

So what am I missing here?  I doubt it is Bjarne who made a mistake :D

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you are focused on the context that example was given?

Comment: yes, I am pretty sure ! :)
usually he marks a wrong code with a comment saying error or something. not this time

Comment: It's just a simple mistake. That's all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The updated version has the following:

```
void f(vector<double>& v)
{
    double d1 = v[1]; // copy the value of the double referred to by v.operator[](1) into d1
    v[2] = 7; // place 7 in the double referred to by the result of v.operator[](2)
    v.push_back(d1); // give push_back() a reference to d1 to wor k with
}
```

So it was probably fixed for the next printing.